# PHP file_get_contents() returns an unencoded string

Tags: php, string, encoding

Here's the code:

```
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
$google = file_get_contents("https://www.google.ru/search?q=Путин");
echo $google;
```

It returns me kind of this string:

```
%253D66%252B%25D0%259F%25D1%2580%25D0%25B8%25D0%25B2%25D0%2
```

I need to get readable russian letters

Comment: That's an *encoded* string. URL-encoded to be precise. Try [`rawurldecode`](http://php.net/rawurldecode).

Comment: @deceze now that returns me kind of this: `镱眇噔桦� 忸滂蝈朦 噔蝾, 眍 礤� 忸珈铈眍耱� <br>
镱珥嚓铎栩� � 龛�... 2. 入� � 锣� 羼螯 驽豚龛� `

Comment: Well, I don't know what it's *supposed* to be. Perhaps not UTF-8.

Comment: Yes that's not what I need.

Comment: Is there a question that you'd like to ask?  Leaning toward "Off-topic: Why isn't my code working"

Comment: It should return russian letters, instead of this I get unreadable thing

Comment: @JoeDoe Why should it return russian letters? You get the whole HTML source of the page back of course which is **not** only russian letters.

Comment: I can't replicate this, it displays the source code of the address in the `file_get_contents` call, as you would expect.

Comment: Isn't there any way to decode this unreadable things to russian letters?

Comment: Presumably there is, but you’re also not using any sort of official API, and Google is probably interested in not letting anyone simply use their site this way, so it may be obfuscated in any number of ways. Or there’s some much more benign explanation. But in the end you’re asking us to decode something from a 3rd party without specification, so… ‍♂️